# Работа с кнопками JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть анимация и 4 кнопки: *Быстрее*, *Медленнее*, *Стоп*, *Старт*. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии *Старт*, кнопка *Стоп* была неактивна, но если нажать потом *Медленнее* или *Быстрее*, то становилась доступной?

```js
"use strict";
var frames = [
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cc00ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffccff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff66ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff6666/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ffffff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/d010ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ad01ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/123456/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/6543ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/cc56ff/000000',
  'http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/65ccf1/000000'
]
var currentFrame = 0
var img = document.getElementById("animation");
var frameTime = 100
var interval = null

function animate() {
  currentFrame += 1;
  if (currentFrame > frames.length - 1) {
    currentFrame = 0;
  }
  img.src = "images/" + frames[currentFrame];
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}

function start() {
  stop();
  interval = setInterval(animate, frameTime);
}

function faster() {
  frameTime -= 50;
  if (frameTime <= 20) {
    frameTime = 20;
  }
  if (interval != null) {
    start();
  }
}

function slower() {
  frameTime += 50;
  if (frameTime >= 1500) {
    frameTime = 1500;
  }
  if (interval != null) {
    start();
  }
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img id="animation" src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/ff00ff/000000" style="margin: 120px 0 100px 0; padding-top: 10px; border: 4px solid #e0e0e0;">
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <button onclick="faster()">Быстрее</button>
  <button onclick="slower()">Медленнее</button>
  <button onclick="stop()">Стоп</button>
  <button onclick="start()">Старт</button>
</div>
```

Comment: ввести переменную вроде allowStop

Answer (score 1):

```js
"use strict";
var frames = ['s1.gif', 's2.gif', 's3.gif', 's4.gif', 's5.gif', 's6.gif', 's7.gif', 's8.gif', 's9.gif', 's10.gif', 's11.gif'];
var currentFrame = 0;
var frameTime = 100;
var interval = null;
var img = document.getElementById("animation");

function animate() {
  currentFrame += 1;
  if (currentFrame > frames.length - 1) { currentFrame = 0; }
  img.src = "images/" + frames[currentFrame];
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(interval);
  interval = null;
}

function start() {
  stop();
  interval = setInterval(animate, frameTime);
}

function faster() {
  frameTime -= 50;
  if (frameTime <= 20) { frameTime = 20; }
  if (interval != null) { start(); }
  document.querySelector(".btn-stop").disabled = false;
}

function slower() {
  frameTime += 50;
  if (frameTime >= 1500) { frameTime = 1500; }
  if (interval != null) { start(); }
  document.querySelector(".btn-stop").disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <img id="animation" src="images/s1.gif" style="margin: 120px 0 100px 0; padding-top: 10px; border: 4px solid #e0e0e0;">
</div>
<div style="text-align: center;">
  <button onclick="faster()" class="btn-fast">Быстрее</button>
  <button onclick="slower()" class="btn-slow">Медленнее</button>
  <button onclick="stop()" class="btn-stop" disabled>Стоп</button>
  <button onclick="start()" class="btn-start">Старт</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const start = document.getElementById('start');
const stop = document.getElementById('stop');
const slow = document.getElementById('slow');
const fast = document.getElementById('fast');


start.addEventListener('click', startClickHandler);

function startClickHandler() {
  stop.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  // Действия по обработке события клика
}

slow.addEventListener('click', slowClickHandler);
fast.addEventListener('click', fastClickHandler);

function slowClickHandler() {
  enableStop();
  // Действия по обработке события клика
}

function fastClickHandler() {
  enableStop();
  // Действия по обработке события клика
}

function enableStop() {
  stop.removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="stop">Stop</button>
<button id="slow">Slow</button>
<button id="fast">Fast</button>
```